# Databinding does not exist

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I have used Databinding library for my android application. It works well, until i upgraded my gradle from 3.0.1 to 3.1.4. Now Databinding library showing error for all generated binding class,

**error: cannot find symbol
import android.databinding.DataBindingComponent;
                          ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: package android.databinding**.

Answer (score 0):

Databinding must match the gradle version.. if you updated gradle version to 3.1.4 you should update databinding to 3.1.4 as well

Comment: for enable databinding, the following code is enough or we need to add in dependency implementation, dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }

Comment: yep you must add databinding { enabled true } but since you wrote it worked i assumed you added it..